# Different solutions to equation with trigonometric functions

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The equation is $\left(\frac{1}{cos\,x}+\frac{1}{sin\,x}\right)(sin\,x+cos\,x)=cot\,x+1$ where $x\in(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$. Let's simplify this in two different ways.

| First Method | Second Method |
| --- | --- |
| $\left(\frac{1}{cos\,x}+\frac{1}{sin\,x}\right)(sin\,x+cos\,x)=cot\,x+1$ | $\left(\frac{1}{cos\,x}+\frac{1}{sin\,x}\right)(sin\,x+cos\,x)=cot\,x+1$ |
| $\left(\frac{sin\,x+cos\,x}{cos\,x\,sin\,x}\right)(sin\,x+cos\,x)=cot\,x+1$ | $\left(\frac{1}{cos\,x}\right)(sin\,x+cos\,x)+\left(\frac{1}{sin\,x}\right)(sin\,x+cos\,x)=cot\,x+1$ |
| $\frac{(sin\,x+cos\,x)^2}{cos\,x\,sin\,x}=cot\,x+1$ | $\frac{sin\,x}{cos\,x}+1+1+\frac{cos\,x}{sin\,x}=cot\,x+1$ |
| $\frac{(sin\,x+cos\,x)^2}{cos\,x\,sin\,x}=\frac{cos\,x}{sin\,x}+1$ | $\frac{sin\,x}{cos\,x}+2+\frac{cos\,x}{sin\,x}=\frac{cos\,x}{sin\,x}+1$ |
| $\frac{(sin\,x+cos\,x)^2}{cos\,x\,sin\,x}=\frac{(cos\,x+sin\,x)}{sin\,x}$ | $\frac{sin\,x}{cos\,x}=-1$ |
| $\frac{(sin\,x+cos\,x)}{cos\,x\,sin\,x}=\frac{1}{sin\,x}$ | $x=-\frac{\pi}{4}$ |
| $\frac{sin\,x+cos\,x}{cos\,x}=1$ |  |
| $sin\,x+cos\,x=cos\,x$ |  |
| $sin\,x=0$ |  |
| $x=0$; invalid solution |  |

This first method seems an invalid solution because $sin\,x=0$ is not in the domain of the given original equation. Can someone please help me understand the difference ? Thank you.

Comment: You lost the solution $x=-\pi/4$ when you divided both sides of the equation by $\sin(x)+\cos(x)$.

Comment: I see, dividing both sides by $sin(x)+cos(x)$, assumes that $sin(x)+cos(x)\ne0$.

If $sin(x)+cos(x)=0$, then $sin(x)=-cos(x)$ and since its given $x\in(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ the answer would be $x=-\frac{\pi}{4}$.

This mean that dividing by a function on both sides, we have to be careful, because we make the implicit assumption that $f(x)\ne0$. Thank you.

Comment: *Third method* : Tangent half-angle substitution $x=2\tan^{-1}(t)$ gives the nice $\tan \left(2 \tan ^{-1}(t)\right)+1=0$

Comment: Rather than cancelling, subtract and factor -- this makes "both" factors easier to see: \begin{align*} \frac{(\sin x + \cos x)^2}{\sin x \cos x} - \frac{\sin x + \cos x}{\sin x} &= 0   \\ \frac{\sin x + \cos x}{\sin x}\left( \frac{\sin x + \cos x}{\cos x} - 1\right) &= 0 \end{align*}  The first factor gives the $-\pi/4$ solution.  The second factor gives the $0$ solution which is rejected by the form of the original equation.  (The $x = 0$ spurious solution dropped out of your second method when you cancelled $\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$ from both sides.)